# define variable file conditionally fails when supplying variable from command line in ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to define variable file conditionally in ansible-playbook, the variable file will be included
if a variable called "location" will be passed via command line
but looks like the a variable name timezone which is mentioned in the variable file is not set 
and I am getting " The error was: 'timezone' is undefined" when I run the playbook as see below:

```
ansible-playbook na_ontap_playbook.yml -e "location=Austin"
```

here is the section from the playbook:

```
- name: Conditionally load variables according to location
  vars:
   location: "{{ location }}"
   cluster:  "{{ storage }}"
  include_vars:
    file: Austin.yml
    name: Austin_configurations
  when: location  == 'Austin'
```

Comment: can you show contents of Austin.yml

Answer (score 0):

We're missing pieces of the puzzle to actually fix the Ansible error.

However, you can try:

`ansible-playbook na_ontap_playbook.yml -e "location=Austin" -e "timezone=US"`

Comment: the austin.yml  contains one line :timezone: America/Los_Angeles

Comment: in your playbook where are you accessing timezone variable